# MySQL search in array of JSON objects

Tags: mysql, sql, json

Lets say I have a JSON column `json` with the following data:

```
+----+-----------------+
| id | json            |
+====+=================+
| 1  | [               |
|    |   {             |
|    |     "type":"a", |
|    |     "id":11111  |
|    |   },            |
|    |   {             |
|    |     "type":"a", |
|    |     "id":22222  |
|    |   },            |
|    |   {             |
|    |     "type":"b", |
|    |     "id":11111  |
|    |   }             |
|    | ]               |
+----+-----------------+
| 2  | [               |
|    |   {             |
|    |     "type":"b", |
|    |     "id":11111  |
|    |                 |
|    |   },            |
|    |   {             |
|    |     "type":"b", |
|    |     "id":22222  |
|    |                 |
|    |   },            |
|    |   {             |
|    |     "type":"c", |
|    |     "id":11111  |
|    |   }             |
|    | ]               |
+----+-----------------+
```

Is there a way to determine if there is an entry in this array which has `type = a` AND `id = 11111` (in the same object), such that ROW 1 would be returned but not ROW 2?

What i've tried is something like

```
SELECT * 
  FROM table 
 WHERE json->>"$[*].type" = "a" 
   AND json->>"$[*].id" = 11111
```

but that's not for the same entry.

Answer (score 2):

Ofcourse I didn't stop looking - and found the solution after 3 hours of trail and error. Feeling a little stupid now I know the solution.

```
SELECT *
  FROM table
 WHERE JSON_CONTAINS(json, JSON_OBJECT('type', 'a', 'id', 11111));
```